# How to round decimal value in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

Am calculating small values in decimal, Expected result is = 345.00 but Result getting is = 345.0000

my code is this `decimal temp= 6900 * ( 5 / 100);`

temp = 345.0000 how to round this ? I want to show 345.00 ? whats my mistake here ?
I tried this code `Math.Round(tempdiscountprice, 2);` also but it wont work here. Help me

Comment: looks like it is the problem of showing/displaying not rounding.

Comment: Thanks guyz, I got now I used this code `temp.ToString("N2")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're showing your real code.  The following will give a result of 0, because (5 / 100) is evaluated using integer arithmetic:

```
decimal temp = 6900 * (5 / 100);
Console.WriteLine(temp.ToString()); // result is 0
```

If you use decimal, you will get the following:

```
decimal temp = 6900 * (5M / 100);
Console.WriteLine(temp.ToString()); // result is 345.00
```

However the decimal type does preserve trailing zeroes:

```
decimal temp = 6900 * (5.0000M / 100);
Console.WriteLine(temp.ToString()); // result is 345.0000
```

Preserving trailing zeroes like this was introduced in .NET 1.1 for more strict conformance with the ECMA CLI specification.

But there's nothing to stop you formatting the output with two decimals, e.g.:

```
decimal temp = 6900 * (5.0000M / 100);
Console.WriteLine(temp.ToString("N2")); // result is 345.00
```

Comment: Hi Joe, I tried `temp.ToString("N2")` work fine Thanks. My Original Code is price = 6900.00 & Tax = 5.00.

Answer (score 2):

As `user2864740` has pointed out above, the problem is not with your rounding, but with displaying the value as a string. Try:

```
 decimal temp = 345.0000m;
 String.Format("{0:0.00}", temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you showing us wrong code because this doesn't get `345.00` or `345.0000` as a result. It always gets `0`.

Your `temp` should be `0` because since you doing [*integer division*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), your `5 / 100` is always `0`. That's why your `temp` will `6900 * 0` then it will be `0`.

If you show us the right code, your problem looks like *showing* problem instead of *rounding* problem.

If you want to format your number as a string, take a look at;

- [`Custom Numeric Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0c899ak8.aspx)